# How to break on specific Guid using Visual Studio Conditional Breakpoint

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I want to use a conditional breakpoint to break when a variable of type Guid has a particular value.

I know how to add a conditional breakpoint. I've tried to write a condition like this:

```
departmentId == new Guid("MYGUIDHERE")
```

But this does not work, it doesn't break. Can anyone tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: Did you forget to add `.ToString()` method? You're comparing an Id (maybe `int`) with a `Guid`. It's type mismatch.

Comment: @AnhTriet: The Id is also of type Guid. It's possible to compare Guids directly in "normal code", but the conditional breakpoint evaluator seems to not support it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have tried setting the conditional break point as you did, but it shows the error:[image: Error]

I guess that action is not supported. So, the alternative way should be:

```
departmentId.ToString() == "MYGUIDHERE"
```

In my example, the expression would be:

```
deptId.ToString() == "ca761232-ed42-11ce-bacd-00aa0057b223"
```

Another way is using [Guid.Parse(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
deptId == Guid.Parse("ca761232-ed42-11ce-bacd-00aa0057b223")
```

Comment: I like the Guid.Parse option as it eliminates ambiguity in the ToString() return value. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I find that ToString is not supported either in a conditional breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

if departmentId is of type Guid.

```
departmentId.toString() == "your guid"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there. I had to match the .ToString() return value of my Guid to the string value I was comparing against. Information about Guid.ToString() I found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I find that ToString is not supported either in a conditional breakpoint

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a normal breakpopint
2. hover your mouse until you see the two signs
3. Click the left one
4. Check the Conditions
5. Add your condition departmentId.toString() == "your guid"

[image]

Comment: I know about conditional breakpoints. The question is about how to express a condition for comparing guids. Perhaps this was not clear from my question.